# What is the best way to show eshop products inside a blog article?

Tags: usability, selling-ux, product-placement

I am having troubles with placing multiple eshop products into / near a picture that is in an article on the supporting blog. These products are related to the content in the picture (e.g picture of kitchen with various kicthen products in it). I need to place 1 to 4 or 5 products and want to keep it also mobile friendly because there's over 80 % traffic from mobile devices.

[image: multiple products]

This is what I have so far. I am wondering if there's a better way? On smaller resolution it must be collapsed even more so that just one product would be visible.

Also I cannot place this stuff to the left or right side of the picture because there's another content (on desktop resolution).

Another option would be to use "pins" that are placed in the picture itself but to show its detail in a popover it would require one more action from the user and displaying it on smaller resolution could be hard.

Thank you for every idea.

Answer (score 2):

A good way would be to use carousels yet they are not the most converting elements. The only thing that you need to pay attention when using carousels on mobile is to use strong cues as it is easy for the user to not see that that`s a carousel. 
Example :

[image: From NNGroup]

Comment: Yeah, i read https://www.nngroup.com/articles/mobile-carousels/ and it is probably the best solution one can come up with. I will also reduce the size of the product on smaller resolutions. Thank you anyway.